# Iterating over three lists simultaneously

Tags: java, java-8

The following code is using indexed for loop:

```
List<A> a = ..;
List<B> b = ..;
List<C> c = ..;

// a.size() == b.size() == c.size() - fundamental business logic assumption

int size = a.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  doSthWith(a.get(i));
  doSthWith(b.get(i));
  doSthWith(c.get(i));
}
```

Is this possible to further simplify the code and not use the index to iterate over three lists simultaneously?

Comment: You might use iterator per list to get rid of the index, but this is unlikely to simplify the code.

Comment: Would the iterator version iterate over lists in order like this: `a[0], a[1], a[2], .., b[0], b[1], b[2], .., c[0], c[1], c[2], ..` or like this: `a[0], b[0], c[0], a[1], b[1], c[1], ..`? I need the second one.

Comment: A generic implementation might look like this: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Iterator<Integer>[] iterators = new Iterator[]{ a.iterator(), b.iterator(), c.iterator() };` -- here you group any number of iterators from your collections; and `while ( iterators[0].hasNext() ) { for ( final Iterator<Integer> iterator : iterators ) { System.out.println(iterator.next()); } }` -- here you traverse iterators in the following order: i0[0], i1[0], i2[0], ... i0[n], i1[n], i2[n].

Comment: @weno is your question specific to 3 or would apply to 'n'  lists?

Comment: Can you redesign your lists into one? [Anti-pattern parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are referring to the list by its interface, you should always prefer using an `Iterator` as opposed to `get()`, because you do not know whether the latter will be equally efficient.

```
Iterator<A> aIterator = aList.iterator();
Iterator<B> bIterator = bList.iterator();
Iterator<C> cIterator = cList.iterator();

while (aIterator.hasNext()) {
    assert bIterator.hasNext();
    assert cIterator.hasNext();
    A a = aIterator.next();
    B b = bIterator.next();
    C c = cIterator.next();
}
assert !bIterator.hasNext();
assert !cIterator.hasNext();
```

You could create your own `Iterator` which encapsulates the above logic:

```
for (Three<A, B, C> three : ThreeIterator.iterate(aList, bList, cList)) {
    A a = three.getA();
    B b = three.getB();
    C c = three.getC();
}
```

```
public class ThreeIterator<A, B, C> implements Iterator<Three<A, B, C>> {
    private final Iterator<A> aIterator;
    private final Iterator<B> bIterator;
    private final Iterator<C> cIterator;

    public ThreeIterator(Collection<A> aCollection, Collection<B> bCollection, Collection<C> cCollection) {
        aIterator = aCollection.iterator();
        bIterator = bCollection.iterator();
        cIterator = cCollection.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        boolean result = aIterator.hasNext();
        if (result) {
            assert bIterator.hasNext();
            assert cIterator.hasNext();
        } else {
            assert !bIterator.hasNext();
            assert !cIterator.hasNext();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Three<A, B, C> next() {
        return new Three<>(aIterator.next(), bIterator.next(), cIterator.next());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        aIterator.remove();
        bIterator.remove();
        cIterator.remove();
    }

    public static <A, B, C> Iterable<Three<A, B, C>> iterate(List<A> aList, List<B> bList, List<C> cList) {
        return new Iterable<Three<A, B, C>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Three<A, B, C>> iterator() {
                return new ThreeIterator<>(aList, bList, cList);
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<Three<A, B, C>> spliterator() {
                int size = aList.size();
                assert bList.size() == size;
                assert cList.size() == size;
                return Spliterators.spliterator(iterator(), size, 0);
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Three<A, B, C> {
    private final A a;
    private final B b;
    private final C c;

    public Three(A a, B b, C c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If all three lists are to be iterated together as you expect, that means they are tightly related and qualify to be an object of some type. It involves a design simplification beforehand.

```
Class MyClass {
   A a;
   B b;
   C c;
}
```

Then I'll be having a `List<MyClass>` instead of three lists with related data. This will simplify your code in long run as well.

And, to answer your question, whatever you are using currently seems very naive but the most readable way of doing this if you are not taking the toil of making a class.

Comment: I think the OP's question is more about an algorithm of traversing n-iterators (not necessarily three of `A`, `B`, and `C`), not about the design.

Comment: @fluffy Agree in your understanding of the question. However I consider this answer more helpful than any answer that tries to answer the question as asked. Mohammed Anees A is right in suggesting that a redesign is the way to go.

Comment: @OleV.V. I guess it's not really clear in OP's question. What if `A`, `B`, and `C` are unrelated things and the a.size==b.size==c.size is only an edge case invariant for a particular situation the OP encountered?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` function:

```
a.forEach(o -> doSthWith(o));
```

Also you can use function for handling each list:

Functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ListConsumer<T extends Iterable> {
    void accept(T ... t);
}
```

Realization:

```
    ListConsumer<List> function = (list) -> {
        for (List l:
             list) {
            doSthWith(l);
        }
    };
```

Using:

```
    List a = new ArrayList();
    List b = new ArrayList();
    function.accept(a, b);
```